# Wrong SQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

I am trying to run a `SQL` statement in `Java` and I am getting syntax

```
String number,key; //populate number and key.
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) 
                          from users_transition 
                         where phoneNumber =" +number +"and randKey="+key);
```

In `MySQL` database, `phoneNumber` is `BigInt(20)` and `key` is `Int(11)`.

Also, according to [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html). The table 5.1 says that types in `MYSQl` can be converted to what types in Java. Doesnt the other way round would work too?

Here's the ERROR

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'randKey=9999' at line 1

Comment: What error do you get? It could be a missing space before the `and`.

Comment: @user432  Indeed. tHat is what the error was.

Comment: [Start using PrepredStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: @user432 I was going to delete the question, but now that there are answers to it, I can not. :/
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tell you what is wrong, and then I'll tell you what is *very* wrong.

**What is wrong**

First, you are building a query which `where` has missing spaces (and possibly missing quotes):

```java
String number,key; //populate number and key.
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) "
                     + "from users_transition "
                     + "where phoneNumber =" +number +" and randKey="+key)";
//                                                     ^ you missed a space here
```

**What is *very* wrong**

Your query is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) (please read the link, it provides a humorous example and tips on solving the problem). Use prepared statements to do this kind of thing:

```java
String number, key;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) "
                                           + "from users_transition "
                                           + "where phoneNumber=? "
                                           + "  and randKey=?");
// The question marks are place holders for values
// You can assign this values with setXXX() methods
ps.setString(1, number);
ps.setString(2, randKey);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
// Do whatever you need to do with the ResultSet
```

Comment: Does the link explain, why PreparedStatement are not prone to SQL Injection Attacks?

Comment: Just read it (and laugh a bit)... It says what would happend if you don't use prepared statements (and come accross a smart-ass bully). A Prepared Statement sanitizes any input you place in it, so it ensures that no rogue code can be executed taking advantage of flawed security in your queries; it also helps you write cleaner and easier-to-mantain code, as you separate the query text from its parameters; it also makes explicit type conversions (`setString()`, `setInt()`, `setDouble()`, etcetera)... in the case of strings it takes away the need for quoting... many advantages, don't you think?

Comment: Yes .. see this java reference http://bobby-tables.com/java.html. In short, the prepared statement will only yield an error when something is inserted into the statement, whereas if a statement string is created, multiple statements can be erroneously executed.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a space between the number and the `AND` operator:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from users_transition where phoneNumber =" +number +" and randKey="+key);
//                                                                                           ^
```

You should replace the query with prepared statement, and use query parameters. This would help you not only avoid simple errors like this, but also make your code immune to SQL injection attacks.

```
String sql = "select count(*) from users_transition where phoneNumber =? and randKey=?";
PreparedStatement getCount = con.prepareStatement(sql);
getCount.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal(number));
getCount.setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal(randKey));
```

Comment: I just want to state here that I have no problem that this was posted. It is not only the correct answer but also expands on the importance of using `PreparedStatement` which is a point not included in the comment.